# Onload image fires too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function checkPic(pic){

    var elm = $('img[src$="' + pic + '"]').closest('.loading');
    var img = elm.find("img");

    var imgWidth = img.width();
    var elmWidth = elm.width();

    if(img.length > 0 && Math.round(imgWidth) == Math.round(elmWidth)){     
        var imgHeight = img.height();
        var imgWidth = img.width();

        var reduce = Math.round(imgWidth / 28);
        var endHeight = imgHeight - reduce;

        elm.css({"height": endHeight + "px", "overflow": "hidden"});
    }
}
```

I'm using this to crop an image as soon as it loads:

```
<div class="loading">
    <img src="picURL" onload="setTimeout( function(){checkPic(picURL, this.width, this.height);}, 500);" style="width: 100%; display: block;">
</div>
```

With the delay of 500ms, it works most of the time, especially when the image is already cached, but it's just a workaround.

When it doesn't work then the function receivs the wrong dimensions and crops too much.

So is there a way to call the function only when the image is really 100% loaded and has the correct dimension information?

Comment: If possible, make the math using [naturalWidth/Height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight), that way you don't need any timeout at all.

Comment: I just trtied checkPic(picURL, this.naturalWidth, this.naturalHeight); but it's still the same result. Have I done this correctly?